# JBoss JMS storing queue files

Tags: java, jboss, queue, hornetq, jbossmq

I use both JBoss AS 4 (JBoss MQ) and  JBoss AS 7 (Hornet Q). I would like to configure the place of storing the queue. 
In destination of JBoss AS 4 /jboss/server/default/deploy I have default-ds.xml which I believe is configuration of storing queue in database :

DefaultDS

```
<xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
 <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:h2:${jboss.server.data.dir}${/}h2${/}localDB;LOCK_TIMEOUT=360000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</xa-datasource-property>
 <user-name>sa</user-name>
<min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
      <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
 <track-connection-by-tx />
<metadata>
   <type-mapping>Hypersonic SQL</type-mapping>
</metadata>
 </xa-datasource>
```

I would like to know is there such file in JBOSS AS 7 by hornetQ which will help me to configure storing queues. I need to keep the queue between restarts of server , etc. Where is the file? Is it just standalone.xml?

Answer (score 1):

HornetQ only supports file persistence. HornetQ uses a set of binary journal files to store the messages in the queues.

The information by default is stored in `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/data (messagingbindings, messagingjournal and messaginglargemessages directory)`.

You can change the default directory, modifying the [messaging subsystem](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Messaging+configuration) in the `standalone.xml` file.

Eg

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">
   <hornetq-server>
      <!-- first of all we want to use a journal on disk (this is important) -->
      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
      <journal-directory path="path/to/journal" relative-to="user.home"/>
      <bindings-directory path="path/to/bindings" relative-to="user.home"/>
      <large-messages-directory path="path/to/large-message" relative-to="user.home"/>
      <paging-directory path="path/to/paging" relative-to="user.home"/>

      <!-- ... -->
   </hornetq-server>
</subsystem>
```

Note the path is always relative to relative-to property (system property, in this example user home) . Not is possible define absolute path.